# Problem of link tracking on AMP pages Via GTM & Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, amp-html

I can't track outbound link click tracking on amp pages with Google Tag Manager.

I used before Event Label ${outboundLink} - but now I don't get the link details. Instead of, I get (not set) on Google Analytics.

How can I know what is the problem and how to get data of the link details when click on the link on amp pages?

Answer (score 2):

Before you can consume the user defined AMP variable, "outboundLink", you need to declare the variable as an element level data attribute and set its value. To do this you would decorate your a tag with data-vars-some-arbitrary-variable-name. For your code, `${outboundLink}`, you want data-vars-outbound-link="[replace with your IRL]". Once you set the variable, you can consume it with the standard camelCase `${someArbitraryVariableName}`.

So `<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" data-vars-outbound-link="stackoverflow.com">` will have the AMP variable `${outboundLink}` and the value with be "stackoverflow.com".

for more info see https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-analytics/analytics-vars.md